# Alt + Tab is not showing the forms when Form.Owner is set

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an application (VB.NET) with the name MainForm and other child forms without using MDI Container. The child forms are based on assign to the MainForm with Me.Owner = MainForm

When I press Alt + Tab, for switching between these form, the Windows is showing the MainForm only unless I remove Me.Owner = Nothing it's working as expected again.

I tried `Call SetWindowLong` on Onload function but not luck. I am still looking for the solution.

EDIT

Actually it's easy for reproduced, I created very simple project.

[Simple Application](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=2D124607DC69BEDF&resid=2D124607DC69BEDF%211816&authkey=ABEfBJbgBZqoYUc)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Form2 As New Form2
    Form2.Owner = Me ' Alt+Tab only Show Form1, not showing Form2.
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Disable Owner property is working fine again.

Please check my [teamview recording](https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=2d124607dc69bedf&resid=2D124607DC69BEDF!1824&parId=2D124607DC69BEDF!249&authkey=!). Actually it's original form without change anything.

@Royce Your solution still not working, it's throw Win32Exception from my side.

Comment: Just for clarification, I believe what the *op* means is that it is not possible to switch back to the owner window using Alt-Tab, if the owner is set on a modeless dialog. I can confirm this is indeed the case, and provoked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854317/is-there-a-built-in-shortcut-key-for-selecting-the-owner-of-the-currently-active

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the [ShowInTaskbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property to `True`.

Comment: Actually it's already set. In the Taskbar I saw all forms also.

Answer (score 0):

Ran your example on my machine (Windows 10) and both windows showed up in my Alt-Tab menu ([screenshot](http://puu.sh/mhfW9/74bc462c09.png)).

In your original program, make sure that the `FormBorderStyle` property of either window is not set to one of the two `ToolWindow` options and that `ShowInTaskbar` is True.

Otherwise, you  might try changing the CreateParams of your second form to exclude WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW extended style bit by doing something similar to this:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle And (Not &H80)
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's not resolved my issue. I am using Windows 8 64 bit. My customer is using windows 7, 8 still face the problem too. I added recording.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been 'And' instead of 'Or'. Does it work for you now? Also, I tried to run your example in Windows 8 compatibility mode and I was still able to see both forms, so if this doesn't work, I have absolutely no idea how to make it work for you. I recommend you try your example on another pc and see if it works there.

Comment: Yes, I tried with Windows 10 and it's working as expected. I have no idea why it's not working from my side and the Customer. I tried all your solution. Is this probably a windows bug?

Comment: Probably not, though I can't be sure since I can't reproduce your bug.